# Scatter chart point click is not rendering properlly

Tags: highcharts

In Scatter chart I have put a overlay div for point click, but when i click the same marker multiple times without moving my mouse pointer it is not considering it to be a click on point and it is considering it as click on chart

Comment: Could you show example with that issue? On jsFiddle maybe?

Comment: sorry I can't do that, it has got lot of data that comes from other pages. I can't tell you for sure whether the issue can be reproduced in a js fiddle. I'm sure i can explain you the issue

Comment: I've defined events for click on both marker and chart. when we click on chart the marker goes to deselected state. and if we click on the same marker (selected) marker its state remains selected. Here the issue is if we make continuous clicks on the same marker without moving the mouse in between the clicks, from the second click onwards it is taking the click as chart click not on marker.

Comment: But there may be a lot of dependencies - like do you have the latest version for Highcharts? Maybe you have some other libraries which creates issue? Try to simplify example, so if this is a bug it could be fixed. Could you try to recreate issue on jsFiddle? Just for me it works really fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/FjaJH/

Comment: instead i can let you see the issue if it is possible for us to have a skype call or so.

Comment: I would rather see upgraded my example with that issue..